# Is it possible to get command arguments now executing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I want to declare aliases which append argument if no argument specified.

For example,

```
alias vimtutor=‘vimtutor $([ $# -eq 0 ] && echo ja.utf-8)’
```

I expected  executing `vimtutor` with no argument is replaced to `vimtutor ja.utf-8`, but it doesn’t work properly.

So, I tried some tests on bash shell.

```
$ echo $#
0
```

```
$ echo a b c $#
a b c 0
```

```
$ echo $0
-bash
```

And I understood it is impossible to get command arguments now executing in normal way.

Now, I declare shell function showing below,

```
vimtutor(){ /usr/bin/vimtutor $([ $# -eq 0 ] && echo ja.utf-8) “$@“; }
```

It woks as expected but feel not smart way.

Is there any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd say using a function rather than an alias is the right way in this case, as you need to interact with the arguments of the command, which `alias` doesn't let you do (as indicated in the aliases section of the bash man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash - "There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see FUNCTIONS below).")

Comment: Functions are more powerful and have fewer caveats than aliases. The function *is* the smart way!

Comment: Thank you for commenting your opinion! I understand it is not bad way to use shell function. I worried typing alias command to check alias definitions and shell functions does not appear here, It means I should check definitions both aliases and shell functions. If I want to define alias in any way, I will use way Christopher Janson commented!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables $#, $0, etc when used in an alias references your bash session variables; the arguments used when your bash session was started, not the arguments passed to the alias command.

I suggest you put your command in a script, and alias to that script. I.e.

```
$ echo 'vimtutor $([ $# -eq 0 ] && echo ja.utf-8)' > ~/vimtutor.sh
$ chmod +x ~/vimtutor.sh
$ alias vimtutor='~/vimtutor.sh'
```

Comment: would you use a script over a function?

Comment: @njzk2 It really depends on what, where and why. But probably yeah. Assuming the command needs to be available between reboots, it would be easier for other scripts or environments to access the script, or make changes to the script, and just put the alias command in e.g. .bashrc.
But if it doesn't have to be persistent, then yeah, I'd probably go with a function.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! It is nice way to create a shell script (and aliases this). I think it will be better to change placed path or script name in each person’s manner. For example, this script places on hidden directory, such as ~/.scripts , I don’t care this script any more. Or placing  ~/bin/vimtutor-jp or /usr/local/bin/vimtutor-jp, It may omit alias definition because just execute vimtutor-jp!